# How do I get all the files names in one folder using Ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex

These are in a folder:

```
This_is_a_very_good_movie-y08iPnx_ktA.mp4
myMovie2-lKESbDzUwUg.mp4
his_is_another_movie-lKESbDzUwUg.mp4
```

How do I fetch the first part of the string `mymovie1` from the file by giving the last part, `y08iPnx_ktA`? Something like:

```
get_first_part("y08iPnx_kTA") #=> "This_is_a_very_good_movie"
```

Comment: `mymovie1`, where is that coming from? Or do you want `This_is_a_very_good_movie`?

Comment: Can filenames have more than one hyphen in them, or do you normalize the names to remove hyphens before adding the hash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Break the problem into into parts. The method `get_first_part` should go something like:

1. Use [Dir](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Dir.html) to get a listing of files.
2. Iterate over each file and;

   1. Extract the "name" ('This_is_a_very_good_movie') and the "tag" ('y08iPnx_ktA'). The same regex should be used for each file.
   2. If the "tag" matches what is being looked for, return "name".

Happy coding.

---

Play around in the REPL and have fun :-)

Answer (score 1):

Can it be done cleaner than this? REVISED based on @Tin Man's suggestion

```
def get_first_part(path, suffix)
  Dir.glob(path + "*" + suffix + "*").map { |x| File.basename(x).gsub(Regexp.new("#{suffix}\.*$"),'') } 
end

puts get_first_part("/path/to/files/", "-y08iPnx_kTA")
```

Comment: +1 For the clever trick of using a glob with a while card. I would argue that `do/end` and more newlines would make it cleaner, but.. ;-) Why the `map` though?

Comment: Dir.glob returned fully qualified paths to each file. There may be more than one file that matches the pattern. @yozloy wanted just the basename without the suffix. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: The OP doesn't want to give a suffix, he wants to give a sub-string. Add ` + '*'` to your glob and you'll meet his requirement.

Comment: Your solution is a wow! after figure your code out by myself, there is only one spot left I'm not sure `.gsub(Regexp.new("#{suffix}\.*$"))` what I understand is that if escape the dot. so the * repeat the '\.' several time until reach the end of line, but it's only only 1 dot in the '.mp4' extname. what I think is Regexp.new("#{suffix}\..*$"), this make sense to me, although your code totally works, however I don't understand

Comment: When I escape the period (aka dot), it means match the period literally. I did this so that the regex would math the provided suffix string followed by a file suffix. Using your example, It will find aaa-y08iPnx_kTA.mp4 but avoid bbb-y08iPnx_kTA-something-else.mp4.

Answer (score 1):

```
def get_first_part(path, suffix)
  Dir.entries(path).find do |fname|
    File.basename(fname, File.extname(fname)).end_with?(suffix)
  end.split(suffix).first
end
```

Kind of expands on the answer from @Steve Wilhelm -- except doesn't use glob (there's no need for it when we're only working with filenames), avoids Regexp and uses `File.exname(fname)` to the `File.basename` call so you don't have to include the file extension. Also returns the string "This_is_a_very_good_movie" instead of an array of files.

This will of course raise if no file could be found.. in which case if you just want to return `nil` if a match couldn't be found:

```
def get_first_part(path, suffix)
  file = Dir.entries(path).find do |fname|
    File.basename(fname, File.extname(fname)).end_with?(suffix)
  end
  file.split(suffix).first if file
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If the filenames only have a single hyphen:

```
path = '/Users/greg/Desktop/test'
target = 'rb'

def get_files(path, target)
  Dir.chdir(path) do
    return Dir["*#{ target }*"].map{ |f| f.split('-').first }
  end
end

puts get_files(path, 'y08iPnx_ktA')
# >> This_is_a_very_good_movie
```

If there are multiple hyphens:

```
def get_files(path, target)
  Dir.chdir(path) do
    return Dir["*#{ target }*"].map{ |f| f.split(target).first.chop }
  end
end

puts get_files(path, 'y08iPnx_ktA')
# >> This_is_a_very_good_movie
```

If the code is assumed to be running from inside the directory containing the files, then `Dir.chdir` can be removed, simplifying things to either:

```
puts Dir["*#{ target }*"].map{ |f| f.split('-').first }
# >> This_is_a_very_good_movie
```

or

```
puts Dir["*#{ target }*"].map{ |f| f.split(target).first.chop }
# >> This_is_a_very_good_movie
```

Comment: Tim Man Thanks for letting me know the usage of Dir[],